# question about pn junction bais and depletion region

Tags: power-electronics

I am confused about this: In a PN junction, when there there is no voltage applied, diffusion occurs and causes a depletion region to be formed. So diffusion is the main reason for forming a depletion region. However, in case of forward bias the PN junction diffusion current dominates. How does the depletion region shrink in forward bias when its main reason for its formation (the diffusion) dominates?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest thinking of it the other way around. In forward bias the depletion region shrinks and therefore diffusion produces a net current outside the diode.

The depletion region is not charge neutral, it has net charge. The electric field in the depletion region is the integral of this charge. The electric potential is the integral of the field. The depletion region shrinks when applying an external voltage because the potential difference between the p and n sides decreases and a reduction of charge in the depletion region must occur for this to happen.

Comment: i get that but i want to know what physically happen in depletion region like how charge is neutralized i  searched for physical explanation for that every explanation is in terms of field and voltage which doesnt tell what really happens

Comment: @mahmoud Do you know that the charges in the depletion region is also present outside the depletion region? Outside the depletion region there is also electrons and holes that keep the semiconductor neutral. When the depletion region changes size you add or remove electrons and holes at the edge of the depletion region.